# How do I disconnect a user from a voice channel in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, disconnect

I don't know how to make the user leave the voice channel.

I'm trying to make a verify thing, I have it all setup except for the leave voice channel part.

```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel
  var channel = bot.channels.get('614299678300831744');


  if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== 615306755420717143) {
    channel.send(newMember + ' has been verified.');
    let role = newMember.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Verified");
    newMember.addRole(role);
    let verifyEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor("Verificaiton")
    .setDescription("You have been verified")
    .setFooter(newMember.guild.name)
    .setColor("#98AFC7")
    newMember.sendMessage(verifyEmbed);
    newMember.disconnect();
  }
});
```

I don't get any error, but it should disconnect me from the voice channel but can't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is still relevant but since the update you can now do the following.

```
newMember.member.voice.disconnect();
```

Refer to the [VoiceState](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) class method `disconnect`.

Comment: This isn't relevant anymore but thanks for the reply

Answer (score 9):

Instead of `newMember.disconnect();` use `newMember.setVoiceChannel(null);`

Here is the related [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setVoiceChannel)

I use this on my bot and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `.disconnect()` is not a method of the `GuildMember` class. All of the methods that can be used on a `GuildMember` can be found [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

`.disconnect()` is only a method that exists on a `voiceChannel`, and is used to "Disconnect the voice connection, causing a disconnect and closing event to be emitted." [1](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=disconnect)

From what i can tell, there is no possible way to forcibly remove a user from a voice channel.

Comment: Is there any way I can make a voice channel named the user's id, connect them to that channel, then delete it?

Comment: There is no way to forcibly connect someone to a voice channel either, they will have to do it themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the bot create a new voice channel, move the user to the newly created voice channel, delete that channel and thus the user being disconnected

```
let randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000 + 1000)

await receivedMessage.guild.createChannel(`voice-kick-${randomnumber}`, "voice")
await vcUser.setVoiceChannel(receivedMessage.guild.channels.find(r => r.name === `voice-kick-${randomnumber}`))
receivedMessage.guild.channels.find(r => r.name === `voice-${randomnumber}`).delete()
```

Were adding the randomnumber command to make a random number in the VC so that there aren't any VC's that have the same name!

Answer (score 1):

In order to disconnect a user from a voice channel, you can use this way

```
newMember.voice.disconnect();
```

I use this for my bot so it works